# Вставить картинку в ячейку таблицы Word из программы

Tags: c#, .net, ms-word, com

Как можно вставить изображение с помощью программы в ячейку таблицы? Тут приведен пример создания таблицы, а вот как засунуть изображение в ячейку не могу понять.

```
Application wordApp = new Application();
Document wordDoc;
Paragraph wordParag;
Table wordTable;

//создаём новый документ Word и задаём параметры листа
wordDoc = wordApp.Documents.Add(Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing); //создаём документ Word     

// второй параграф, таблица из 10 строк и 2 колонок
wordDoc.Paragraphs.Add(Type.Missing);
wordParag.Range.Tables.Add(wordParag.Range, 10, 2, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
wordTable = wordDoc.Tables[1];
wordTable.Range.Font.Bold = 0;
wordTable.Range.Font.Size = 12;

//задаём ширину колонок и высоту строк
wordTable.Columns.PreferredWidthType = WdPreferredWidthType.wdPreferredWidthPoints;
wordTable.Columns[1].SetWidth(200f, WdRulerStyle.wdAdjustNone);
wordTable.Rows.SetHeight(20f, WdRowHeightRule.wdRowHeightExactly);
wordTable.Rows.Alignment = WdRowAlignment.wdAlignRowCenter;
wordTable.Range.Cells.VerticalAlignment = WdCellVerticalAlignment.wdCellAlignVerticalCenter;
wordTable.Range.Select();
```

Answer (score 2):

Получаете Range нужной ячейки таблицы

```
Range cellRange = wordTable.Tables[1].Cell(1, 1).Range;
```

и вставляете картинку

```
cellRange.InlineShapes.AddPicture(@"C:\blabla.jpg", Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
```

Посмотрите еще документацию по аргументам метода AddPicture (делать ли копию изображения, вставлять ли в range или заменять его).